Single Page Application Session Managment and Spring Security Backend
I have a SPA webapp and spring boot backend. I am using spring security for login ldap authentication and csrf enabled. Now I am a little confuse on how I can implement session management on SPA and make it secured.
Questions:

I store the user's first name, last name and login name in a cookie after a successful login in ldap. Is this ok?login name and user's name since they are not credentials.
Is CSRF token enough for secured SPA? I am a little stuck on decision.

Hope to give me some light/path to take. Thanks

Please ask one question per question, otherwise it becomes too broad / hard to answer. I will therefore provide very short answers. 1) You probably shouldn't expose any info in cookies, user info should be persisted in database and you get access to it when your users authenticates 2) CSRF token mitigates one specific issue - CSRF. You need it since you are using cookies for session management (so that bad actor doesn't send an email to people with malicious hidden link which will trigger an action on their comps using cookies)  But that is not the only issue out there - too broad to answer

your question clearly tells us that you have not done any type of content search for what CSRF is and what oauth2 is. but some blogs said csrf is enough if you are serious about this statement, you need to link your sources. I suggest you read up on what CSRF is, what its purpose is. Then you read up on oauth2 and its purpose as it is clear that this has not been done before asking this question. Here start reading https://portswigger.net/web-security/csrf and https://auth0.com/intro-to-iam/what-is-oauth-2

@JAsgarov, thanks! what I mean is after successful authentication, I am looking at to store the user's firstname and last name in front end and keep them logged in through out the session. I found this link from freecodecamp https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/how-to-persist-a-logged-in-user-in-react/

Yes, session cookie + (cookie-based) protection against CSRF are enough to authorize a SPA on a Spring backend.
Spring session cookies are flagged with SameSite (as it should). So the only thing to do for an SPA to be authorized on a session-based backend it to serve both with the same origin: the browser will attach the session cookie to each REST request from the SPA to the backend. A few options:

serve both through the same reverse proxy (a nginx Docker container, k8s ingres, ...)
in the case where the backend entry point is Spring Cloud Gateway, use a route to serve the SPA assets
in the case where the backend is seen as a single service (monolith or single facade), serve the SPA assets from the static resources of this service (use WebPack proxy or whatever similar feature for your SPA framework during dev)

If you switch to OAuth2 and follow current recommendations for SPAs, you'll need protection against CSRF too. @j-asgarov is right in his comment: CSRF protection is needed as soon as sessions are used (and requests between an SPA and a Spring app with oauth2Login are authorized with sessions). This article I wrote can be useful for such a transition (but you probably don't need OAuth2 if all identities are held in your LDAP, and you don't need features like SSO).

Hi Thanks for the answer, this is exactly the confirmation I need. Yes all roles and identities are all in LDAP. From the bullet points above, I am currently using the 3rd option. I'll mark this answer. Thanks again!
